# Calculating available sessions for appointment booking without using a loop or cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, common-table-expression

This is a very over simplified model but the principle remains. There are available sessions where a resource is available between given times. If you make a reservation it gets stored in the reservation table with a Start Time and duration.

I am able get the gaps between reservation like this

```
;with cte as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartTime)sq, StartTime,DATEADD(MINUTE,Duration,StartTime) as EndTime, Duration
    from @Reservations
)

select StartTime = a.EndTime , EndTime = b.StartTime
    from cte a
    INNER JOIN cte b on a.sq =  b.sq - 1
```

Where I'm struggling is to get the AvailableSessions to be updated to take into account the reservations. I want to return a result set that looks something like the below. Simply, for each of the original slots in AvailableSession will have to be split into more splits dependent on where the reservation starts and ends within the slot.
For example, for the reservation at 1600 the first session will need to be split in two from 1520 to 1600 and so on.

I can think of ways of doing this using cursors and loops but I would prefer a more set based way of doing it. I think it's at the limits of my current sql knowledge.

```
'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 15:20','2020-11-02 16:00' -- the original session is split and ends when the first reservation starts
'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 16:10','2020-11-02 16:35'-- the gap between the first reservation ending and the second starting
'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 16:45','2020-11-02 1720' -- the gap between the 2nd reservation ending and the third starting
'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 17:30','2020-11-02 2000' -- `no reservations made yet so still a contagious block

declare @AvailableSession TABLE (
    ID int,
    Name varchar(50),
    StartTime datetime,
    EndTime datetime
)

insert into @AvailableSession VALUES (1, 'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 15:20','2020-11-02 17:30')
insert into @AvailableSession VALUES (2, 'Quick Tennis', '2020-11-02 17:30','2020-11-02 20:00')

declare @Reservations TABLE
(
    StartTime datetime,
    Duration int
)

insert into @Reservations VALUES ('2020-11-02 16:00',10)
insert into @Reservations VALUES ('2020-11-02 16:35',10)
insert into @Reservations VALUES ('2020-11-02 17:20',10)
```

Comment: Hi - just checking if I have understood this correctly: (1) You have a session that has a start and end time (2) People can reserve time slots within this session? Are there any restrictions on when their timeslot can start and how long it can be for e.g. if a session is from 16:00 to 17:00 could I reserve a slot (assuming it was free) from 16:07 to 16:23? If not, what are the rules about when a time slot can start and how long it can be?

Comment: @NickW, people can book slots within the session. No restrictions on the session so yes you could book 1607 to 1617. There has to be enough free to allow for the duration of the reservation so in the examples 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should work. It may be possible to simplify it by combining steps/CTEs but this is possibly the easiest way to follow my logic:

### Table Creation & Example Data

```
create table reservations (session_id integer, StartTime datetime, duration integer);
create table sessions(session_id integer, StartTime datetime,EndTime datetime);

insert into sessions(session_id, StartTime ,EndTime)
values (1,'2020-12-03 16:00', '2020-12-03 18:00');

insert into reservations(session_id, StartTime , duration)
    values 
     (1, '2020-12-03 16:00',    5) -- Reservation at start of session
     (1, '2020-12-03 16:10',    15),
     (1, '2020-12-03 16:40',    6),
     (1, '2020-12-03 16:46',    3), -- Starts when previous reservation ends
     (1, '2020-12-03 16:52',    17),
     (1, '2020-12-03 17:26',    10),
     (1, '2020-12-03 17:46',    6)
     (1, '2020-12-03 17:55',    5); -- Ends at session end
```

### SQL to Generate Available Slots

```
--Format reservations so that they have a start and end date and a sequence
with calc_resv (session_id, StartTime, EndTime, seq) as 
(
 select 
 session_id
 , StartTime
 , dateadd(mi, duration, StartTime ) as EndTime
 , cast(rank() over (partition by session_id order by StartTime ) as integer) as seq
 from reservations
 ),
 --Combine session and reservation data into 1 table
 data_set (session_id, StartTime, EndTime, seq) as 
 (
     select session_id , StartTime ,EndTime, 0
     from sessions
     union all
     select cr.session_id, cr.StartTime, cr.EndTime, cr.seq
     from calc_resv cr
 ),
 --Calculate available slots by using the end time of current record with the start time of the next record
 avail_slots (session_id, seq, NextStart, NextEnd) as 
 (
 select 
 session_id, seq
 ,case when seq = 0 then StartTime else
    EndTime end as NextStart
 , isnull(lead(startTime) over (order by session_id, seq), (select s.EndTime from sessions s where ds.session_id = s.session_id)) as NextEnd
 from data_set ds
 )
 select * from avail_slots
where NextStart <> NextEnd -- Case where 1st reservation starts at the start of the session or one reservation immediately follows another
 ;
```

### Resulting Dataset

```
session_id  seq NextStart           NextEnd
1           1   2020-12-03 16:05    2020-12-03 16:10
1           2   2020-12-03 16:25    2020-12-03 16:40
1           4   2020-12-03 16:49    2020-12-03 16:52
1           5   2020-12-03 17:09    2020-12-03 17:26
1           6   2020-12-03 17:36    2020-12-03 17:46
1           7   2020-12-03 17:52    2020-12-03 17:55
```

Comment: this is great and has pointed me in the right direction. I'm not sure if they are the most efficient but made some changes around returning the slots if no reservations were made and also dealing with more than one slot